# How is it that $d(x,y)=|{\rm arctan}\ x -{\rm arctan}\ y| $ isn't a complete metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, epsilon-delta, complete-spaces

I'm having trouble understanding  part of this proof:

Take a sequence $x_n=n$. Since $arctan(n)\to \pi/2$, for give $\epsilon>0$, there is N so that $|arctan(n)-\pi/2|<\epsilon/2$ for $n\geq N.$ Hence

$d(x_n,x_m)=|arctan(n) - arctan(m)|\leq|arctan(n) - \pi/2|+|arctan(m) - \pi/2|<\epsilon$.

for $n,m\geq N$. Assume  $d(x,y)\to 0$ for some $x \in R$. Then $pi/2=arctan x$ which is impossible.

What I don't understand is the first part where we say that since $arctan(n) \to \pi/2$ we can have:

$|arctan(n)-\pi/2|<\epsilon/2$

After that I see we use the triangle inequality using this same expression. Why do we substitute the second arctan with $pi/2$ since arctan will never become $\pi/2$ and what is the sole purpose of having this expression $<$ than $\epsilon$/2 and not just $\epsilon$.

Any hint is appreciated, regards.

Comment: It is true that we can never have $\arctan(x) = \pi/2$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, we do have that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\arctan x} = \pi/2$. By definition, this means that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x>N$ we have $|\arctan x - \pi/2|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the definition of convergence: to say that $\arctan(n)$ converges to $\pi/2$ means that for any $\delta>0$, there exists $N$ such that $|\arctan(n)-\pi/2|<\delta$ for all $n\geq N$.  Now given $\epsilon>0$, define $\delta=\epsilon/2$ and use the definition to obtain $N$ such that $|\arctan(n)-\pi/2|<\epsilon/2$ for all $n\geq N$.

The reason to choose $\epsilon/2$ instead of $\epsilon$ here is that you eventually want to show that $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$ whenever $n,m\geq N$ (to satisfy the definition of a Cauchy sequence) and in the course of proving that our $\delta$ will end up getting doubled.